# How can you pass password to GIT on the command line?

Tags: git, command-line, https, passwords

There are plenty of answers out there how to use a GIT credentials manager to save your password and not have it entered every time.

But I need something in the opposite direction - I want to pass the username/password in the command line (no user interaction possible), but I only want to do it ONCE and not store it anywhere. Is this possible?

**Clarification:** This will be used for `git clone` and currently I'm using the URL syntax - `https://username:password@example.com`. However this has the side effect that the URL with the password is stored in the `origin` remote. This I want to avoid.

**Afterthought:** Come to think of it, I could simply change the `origin` URL after cloning is complete... Well, that solves my problem, but I think the question is good enough to stay opened. Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: You will need to clean the history of the command line, as the password will be in there -> `history`

Comment: is this what you are looking for?: git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git

Comment: @Adder - This will be run in an automated script. I think it's not saved anywhere, but I'll check.

Comment: @KarsBarendrecht - This is what I'm doing now, but there's a side effect - the username/password is stored in plain text in the repository's `origin` URL. That's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Pass username/password in the command line. The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

username="$1"
password="$2"

git push "https://$username:$password@githost.example.net/repo.git"
```

To run the script pass arguments:

```
git-script username password
```

Another variant is to define username/password in the environment:

```
username=name
password=pwd
export username password
```

Then the script is simply

```
#!/bin/sh
git push "https://$username:$password@githost.example.net/repo.git"
```

PS. Please make sure `username` and `password` don't contain special
characters or you need to URL-encode them to use in git URIs.

Comment: This approach has a side effect - when cloning, the usename/password is saved in the `origin` repo URL. This is what I'm doing now and what I want to avoid. I think I should have been clearer, I apologize.

Comment: What's wrong in storing password in local `.git/config`? IMO it's not much less secure than using clear password in a script. Anyway you can change the URL after cloning: `git remote set-url origin "https://$username@githost.example.net/repo.git"`. But then you need to enter password every time you access `origin`.

Comment: The thing is - the script isn't saved anywhere. It's generated on the fly (with user input), then executed on remote machine. The next person who needs to do anything with the repository will need to use their own password (well, for pushing/pulling anyway).

Comment: Shared repository under control of a *distributed* VCS?

Comment: Ehh, no. OK, well, actually, it's going to be only me ever working with it. Still it's my password and I'd prefer it wasn't saved anywhere in plain text. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program `expect` to control all input and output to/from a program, including passwords (which are usually read from the terminal and not standard input).

Comment: Nice, I'll keep that in mind if there's nothing better.